# Common Record from 2 tables in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 2 tables. Both the tables contain 2 columns: `id`, `amt`.
Table 1 has these data:

```
id, amt
1,  500;
2,  2000;
4,  1000.
```

Table 2 contains:

```
id, amt
1,  100;
1,  100;
1,  100;
1,  100;
1,  100;
2,  250;
3,  300;
4,  1000;
```

Now my requirement is getting the record which is common id and common amt in both the table. But the challenge here is, id 1 is available in both the table. But the sum(amt) in table 2 with id 1 = amt in table 1 with id 1. I need to pull this record also as a common record. Please help me in this. Thanks.

Comment: Hard to understand what you are asking.   Can you show an example of the output you'd expect and what query you've tried so far?

Comment: 1,500;4,1000; is my required output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like:

```
SELECT *
FROM table1 
JOIN (SELECT id, SUM(amt) as amt FROM table2 GROUP BY id) t2
ON t1.id = t2.id AND t1.amt=t2.amt
```

Comment: It is also working with column details from table 2 also. Thanks Stuart.

Comment: If this is a case, how to do this.

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT id, amt
FROM Table1
INTERSECT
SELECT id, SUM(amt)
FROM Table2
GROUP BY id
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
WITH T2_CTE (id, amt)
AS
(
    SELECT id, SUM(amt)
    FROM table2
    GROUP BY id
)

SELECT t1.id, t1.amt
FROM table1 t1, T2_CTE
WHERE t1.id = T2_CTE.id AND t2.amt = T2_CTE.amt
```